# how to turn my robot with different controllers?

Tags: ros, gazebo, ros-kinetic, rostopic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I using ROS Kinetic and I have built a 4-wheel robot called labrob, which I want to control. The robot can be seen in the following picture:
[Screenshot from 2016-07-25 18-49-27.png](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/ros/14694617997897263.png)

At this robot I have added 2 motors (at the two front wheels) and also differential_drive_controller plugins:

```
  <gazebo>
   <plugin name="differential_drive_controller" filename="libgazebo_ros_diff_drive.so">
           <alwaysOn>true</alwaysOn>
            <updateRate>100</updateRate>
            <leftJoint>joint_f_r_wheel</leftJoint>
            <wheelDiameter>0.4</wheelDiameter>
            <torque>20</torque>
            <commandTopic>motor1/cmd_vel</commandTopic>
            <odometryTopic>odom</odometryTopic>
            <odometryFrame>odom</odometryFrame>
            <robotBaseFrame>base_footprint</robotBaseFrame>
            <robotNamespace>labrob</robotNamespace>
        <legacyMode>true</legacyMode>
   </plugin>
  </gazebo>

  <gazebo>
   <plugin name="differential_drive_controller" filename="libgazebo_ros_diff_drive.so">
           <alwaysOn>true</alwaysOn>
            <updateRate>100</updateRate>
            <leftJoint>joint_f_l_wheel</leftJoint>
            <wheelDiameter>0.4</wheelDiameter>
            <torque>20</torque>
            <commandTopic>motor2/cmd_vel</commandTopic>
            <odometryTopic>odom</odometryTopic>
            <odometryFrame>odom</odometryFrame>
            <robotBaseFrame>base_footprint</robotBaseFrame>
            <robotNamespace>labrob</robotNamespace>
        <legacyMode>true</legacyMode>
   </plugin>
  </gazebo>
```

at the wheels that I want to control. But when I run it in gazebo and then do:

```
rostopic list
```

I cannot see the topics motor1/cmd_vel and motor2/cmd_vel .
If, however, I add only one plugin for controlling both motors at the same time (in this case, the robot doesn't turn) like this:

```
  <gazebo>
   <plugin name="differential_drive_controller" filename="libgazebo_ros_diff_drive.so">
           <alwaysOn>true</alwaysOn>
            <updateRate>100.0</updateRate>
            <leftJoint>joint_f_l_wheel</leftJoint>
            <rightJoint>joint_f_r_wheel</rightJoint>
        <wheelSeperation>0.53</wheelSeperation>
            <wheelDiameter>0.4</wheelDiameter>
            <torque>20</torque>
        <topicName>/labrob/cmd_vel</topicName>
            <odometryTopic>odom</odometryTopic>
            <odometryFrame>odom</odometryFrame>
            <robotBaseFrame>base_footprint</robotBaseFrame>
            <publishWheelJointState>false</publishWheelJointState>
        <legacyMode>true</legacyMode>
            <robotNamespace>labrob</robotNamespace>
   </plugin>
  </gazebo>
```

everything works fine and after `rostopic list` I can see the labrob/cmd_vel topic and publish messages on it.
Could you please tell me what should I change, so I can control the motors separately? Or if there is another type of controller for this task?

Thank you for your answers and your time in advance.

Edited:
I would like to ask what is the difference between `<commandTopic>` and `<topicName>`. None of the two are being identified by the `rostopic list` command. Also is there a relationship in the order I put the xml tags? For example, is it possible that I need to put `<WheelDiameter>` higher or lower in the code so it can be run correctly?
Maybe it should be helpful to add that I get these messages on my terminal after the gazebo roslaunch of my model:

```
SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /robot_description: <?xml version="1....
 * /rosdistro: kinetic
 * /rosversion: 1.12.2
 * /use_sim_time: True

NODES
  /
    gazebo (gazebo_ros/gzserver)
    gazebo_gui (gazebo_ros/gzclient)
    labrob_spawn (gazebo_ros/spawn_model)

ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

core service [/rosout] found
process[gazebo-1]: started with pid [6836]
process[gazebo_gui-2]: started with pid [6843]
process[labrob_spawn-3]: started with pid [6850]
spawn_model script started
[ INFO] [1469543270.209498030]: Finished loading Gazebo ROS API Plugin.
[ INFO] [1469543270.210093847]: waitForService: Service [/gazebo/set_physics_properties] has not been advertised, waiting...
[INFO] [WallTime: 1469543270.297032] [0.000000] Loading model xml from ros parameter
[INFO] [WallTime: 1469543270.299725] [0.000000] Waiting for service /gazebo/spawn_urdf_model
[ INFO] [1469543270.759606848, 0.023000000]: waitForService: Service [/gazebo/set_physics_properties] is now available.
[ INFO] [1469543270.795880524, 0.057000000]: Physics dynamic reconfigure ready.
[INFO] [WallTime: 1469543270.904801] [0.162000] Calling service /gazebo/spawn_urdf_model
[INFO] [WallTime: 1469543271.164199] [0.359000] Spawn status: SpawnModel: Successfully spawned model
[labrob_spawn-3] process has finished cleanly
log file: /home/legged/.ros/log/d963a97a-533b-11e6-bcd8-d07e357c25db/labrob_spawn-3*.log
[ INFO] [1469543271.416237453, 0.359000000]: Laser Plugin (robotNamespace = /), Info: Using the 'robotNamespace' param: '/'
[ INFO] [1469543271.416316758, 0.359000000]: Starting GazeboRosLaser Plugin (ns = /)!
[ INFO] [1469543271.417656784, 0.359000000]: GPU Laser Plugin (ns = /) <tf_prefix_>, set to ""
[ INFO] [1469543271.418835868, 0.359000000]: LoadThread function completed
[ INFO] [1469543271.493016022, 0.359000000]: Starting plugin DiffDrive(ns = labrob/)!
[ WARN] [1469543271.493412015, 0.359000000]: DiffDrive(ns = labrob/): missing <rosDebugLevel> default is na
[ INFO] [1469543271.494464269, 0.359000000]: DiffDrive(ns = labrob/): <tf_prefix> = labrob
[ WARN] [1469543271.494678706, 0.359000000]: DiffDrive(ns = labrob/): missing <publishWheelTF> default is false
[ WARN] [1469543271.494756210, 0.359000000]: DiffDrive(ns = labrob/): missing <publishWheelJointState> default is false
[ WARN] [1469543271.494910558, 0.359000000]: DiffDrive(ns = labrob/): missing <wheelSeparation> default is 0.34000000000000002
[ WARN] [1469543271.495023534, 0.359000000]: DiffDrive(ns = labrob/): missing <wheelAcceleration> default is 0
[ WARN] [1469543271.495097272, 0.359000000]: DiffDrive(ns = labrob/): missing <wheelTorque> default is 5
[ WARN] [1469543271.495259748, 0.359000000]: DiffDrive(ns = labrob/): missing <odometrySource> default is 1
[ WARN] [1469543271.495373758, 0.359000000]: DiffDrive(ns = labrob/): missing <rightJoint> default is right_joint
[ INFO] [1469543271.495906445, 0.359000000]: Starting plugin DiffDrive(ns = labrob/)!
[ WARN] [1469543271.495988728, 0.359000000]: DiffDrive(ns = labrob/): missing <rosDebugLevel> default is na
[ INFO] [1469543271.496986671, 0.359000000]: DiffDrive(ns = labrob/): <tf_prefix> = labrob
[ WARN] [1469543271.497615340, 0.359000000]: DiffDrive(ns = labrob/): missing <publishWheelTF> default is false
[ WARN] [1469543271.497690438, 0.359000000]: DiffDrive(ns = labrob/): missing <publishWheelJointState> default is false
[ WARN] [1469543271.497742833, 0.359000000]: DiffDrive(ns = labrob/): missing <wheelSeparation> default is 0.34000000000000002
[ WARN] [1469543271.497821336, 0.359000000]: DiffDrive(ns = labrob/): missing <wheelAcceleration> default is 0
[ WARN] [1469543271.497865186, 0.359000000]: DiffDrive(ns = labrob/): missing <wheelTorque> default is 5
[ WARN] [1469543271.497912353, 0.359000000]: DiffDrive(ns = labrob/): missing <odometrySource> default is 1
[ WARN] [1469543271.497955545, 0.359000000]: DiffDrive(ns = labrob/): missing <rightJoint> default is right_joint
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/240326/how-to-turn-my-robot-with-different-controllers?/) by [patrchri](https://answers.ros.org/users/26728/patrchri/) on ROS Answers with karma: 354 on 2016-07-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you want to separate your motor's commands, you can :

- use one plugin and change the message type expected for command topic
- write a plugin that control only one motor. This plugin will be called for each of your motor.
- maybe look at [ros_control](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials/?tut=ros_control)

With the code that you have posted :

- maybe you can change the plugins name
  (conflict between two plugins having
  the same name)
- your command topic expected by these plugins should probably be : /labrob/motor1/cmd_vel and /labrob/motor2/cmd_vel

---

Originally posted by [F.Brosseau](https://answers.ros.org/users/22477/f.brosseau/) with karma: 379 on 2016-07-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [patrchri](https://answers.ros.org/users/26728/patrchri/) on 2016-07-26**:
With the code I have used, your recommendations didn't work.
Do i miss something?

For your general recommendations :

1. I don't know how to do it
2. how can I write a non hard coded plugin for generally some motor?
3. I have checked this, but this tutorial doesn't help me for now.

**Comment by [F.Brosseau](https://answers.ros.org/users/22477/f.brosseau/) on 2016-07-27**:
For 1 : there is a tutorial [here](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingMsgAndSrv)

Then you can take the diff drive plugin code and change the msg type expected : [gazebo_git](https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros_pkgs/blob/jade-devel/gazebo_plugins/src/gazebo_ros_diff_drive.cpp)